# Why doesn't PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY leak memory with partially fetched resultsets?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` buffers the query results, how come leaving unfinished queries lying around (Single `PDOStatement->fetch()` on a large resultset in a loop) doesn't leak like a sieve?

The memory results are the same just before the timeout as they are after the first iteration:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO($connstring, $user, $pass);

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, true);

$i = 0;

$s = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_with_tons_of_rows');
$s->execute();
var_dump($s->fetchAll());
var_dump([memory_get_usage(), memory_get_usage(true)]);

do {
    $s = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table_with_tons_of_rows');
    $s->execute();
    $s->fetch();
    var_dump([memory_get_usage(), memory_get_usage(true), $i++]);
} while (true);
```

Does PHP automatically dump the buffer when the refcount on the statement hits 0?

Comment: Yes, surely it does.

Comment: It just seems like the kind of thing that would wait until a GC collection cycle